# Polynomial with integer coefficients-Need a clarification

Tags: polynomials

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjyWcCQOvfs) and there is a question about the polynomial. I couldn't manage to solve it. Well, actually I couldn't really understand what questions is.  So any clarification/solution sketch is much appreciated. Here is the question:

Given a polynomial

$$ P=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$
where $n<\infty$ and $a_i$ is a non-negative integer You can ask me the value of $P$ at any integer value of $x$. Depending on the answer, you can ask me what $P$ is for another integer value of $x^\prime$. Find $P$.

Comment: It sounds like they are telling you that this polynomial can be specified by two points, which means it is a line.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It seems, because of the context of the video, that the problem has not required of a precise answer.